# Как поставить срезы

Tags: python

здесь видно что код не округляет до нужных значений. Должен был выдать результат: 3999.999

```
dlina = 111
dlina0 = str(dlina)
dlina1 = len(dlina0)
a = 3999.99999999
print(round(a, dlina1))
```

здесь выдает 4000.0

вот эта формула тоже не округляет до значений 3999.999

```
dlina = 111
dlina0 = str(dlina)
dlina1 = len(dlina0)
a = 3999.99999999
print(int(a*3999**dlina1)/3999**dlina1)
```

тут выдает такой результат 3999.9999999899924

Comment: `4000.0` на несколько порядков ближе к `3999.99999999` чем `3999.999`. Так что очень даже округляет. А если вам нужно, чтобы при выводе после запятой было 3 знака, `f'{a:.3f}'` даст `4000.000`. Ну и для примера из вопроса - `f'{a:.{len(str(dlina))}f}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему бы просто не округлить?

```
a = 10.4455555
print(round(a,3))
```

```
10.446
```

Если нужно округлить не по мат. правилам (всегда вниз), можно так

```
n = 3
a = 10.4455555
print(int(a*10**n)/10**n)
```

Как это работает. Берем число 10.4455555, умножаем его на `10**n` - в данном случае `10**3` = 1000 (можно сказать, "сдвигаем" десятичную точку вправо на 3 знака). Получаем  10445.5555. Отбрасываем дробную часть с помощью `int()`, получаем 10445. Делим на 1000 - "сдвигаем" точку влево на 3 знака и получаем:

```
10.445
```

Comment: Не всегда округление хорошо проходит. Нада тогда что бы он округлял в меньшую строну. С некоторыми вещами округление идет в большую сторону а это вызывает ошибку

Comment: Не получается решить по вашей формуле

Comment: что именно не получается?

Comment: Мы ведь узнали в через len длину это 3. Значит после точки должно быть только 3 значений а он не правильные значения дает

Comment: так нужно `print(int(a*10**dlina1)/10**dlina1)`, а не `print(int(a*3999**dlina1)/3999**dlina1)`. Это же десятичная система счисления, а не 3999-ичная

Comment: что выполняет значение 10? я думал это длина переменной a до точки

Comment: это основание системы счисления. 10**3 - 10 в 3й степени, т.е. 1000

Comment: Дописал "как это работает" в решение

Comment: да все работает как нужно и ошибок больше не вызывает вроде

Answer (score 1):

У меня всегда костыльные решения, но пока никто нормального не дал:

```
a = str(a)
n = 1
while True:
    try:
        a = a[:-n]
        break
    except:
        n += 1
a = float(a)
```

Проверить возможности нет, прошу прощения.

Comment: Не получается решить по вашей формуле –

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

koef = 10 ** dlina1                           # в вашем случае получите 10 ** 3 == 1000
result = math.floor(koef * a) / koef          # умножим, отбросим дес. часть, разделим
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Подход такой — на примере числа 12.3456789 и желанию сохранить только 3 цифры за десятичной точкой:

1. Десятичную точку сначала сдвинем десятичную точку на 3 позиции *вправо* — получим
   `12345.6789`.
2. Затем отбросим десятичную часть — получим `12345` (десятичная точка по умолчанию в конце).
3. Десятичную точку сдвинем обратно на 3 позиции *влево* — получим `12.345` .

Теперь те же самые пункты, используя Питон:

1. Умножим число на 1000 (что можно выразить как `10 ** 3`).
2. На результат применим функцию `floor()` из встроенного модуля `math`.
3. Результат обратно разделим на 1000.